# SwiftUI + Core Data - best practice for non-changing preloaded data?

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui

I’m two weeks in to attempting SwiftUI coding so very new to all things XCode. I’m trying to understand the best practice way to deal with data that won’t change but is required in my app before first run (roughly 700 records/objects). Is reading in via JSON files to store in Core Data the best way? Then as each view will need access to this would an environment object be best over individual fetchrequests on each one?

Any tutorial/resource recommendations you can point me to would be most appreciated

Comment: yep, i would recommend using Coredata

Comment: I am doing - are you saying reading the data I need to preload via JSON files is a good solution?

Comment: as always...it depends ;) do the preload in the background so that the app quickly starts. Directly show "some" data so the user can have fun with your app. Just inform him that you are still fetching content in the background. don't annoy him with waiting bars. it can take quite a long time to load data to coredata, if they are big. if you need just 1 sec to load it, you can do prefetch, else i would load in background and "prefetch" just a few records.

Comment: Not come across prefetch yet - will look that up! I was meaning preload data to the database on first run (some reference data) of the app as it won’t be edited by the user - will test which way is most performance heavy once I get that far :)